# I am making a personal website, but I am having a hard time figuring out why the borders won't fill

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I added a background for my website but for some reason, the boarders won't fill in. It's like that on mobile too. I also would like to center my navbar because I did it manually because justify content center would not work for me. For my cover page, I just want to fill in the borders.

```js
AOS.init();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu');
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/*navbar*/

.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 38%;
  right: 70;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar * {
  display: inline;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-nav {
  justify-content: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 0 #fff, -2px 0 #fff, 0 2px #fff, 0 -2px #fff, 1px 1px #fff, -1px -1px #fff, 1px -1px #fff, -1px 1px #fff;
}


/*main display text*/

#coverPage {
  background: url(https://wallpapers.com/images/hd/dark-shades-of-purple-j1bf61qb3t5kkk6h.webp)fixed right top;
  min-height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.main-display {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 20px black, -2px 1px 30px black;
}

#title {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.SE {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.bball {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 5000;
}

.gym {
  font-size: 17px;
}

#about-me {
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-me-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup" div>
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">about</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">projects</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<section id="coverPage">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="main-display">
          <h1 class="display-1" id="title" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic" data-aos-duration="2000">NADIR ESMAIL</h1>
          <h2 class="SE" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic" data-aos-duration="2000">software developer</h2>
          <h1 class="bball" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic" data-aos-duration="2000">Basketball fanatic</h1>
          <h1 class="gym" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic" data-aos-duration="2000">Gym enthusiast</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!--About me page-->
<section id="about-me">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="about-title">
        <h1 id="about-me-h1" class="display-5">About</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!--  bootstrap and aos js  -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="nadir.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8c2adfc9c1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Try removing border and padding on the body element.

Comment: Remember that browsers may add styling of their own - margin is one. Remove it on everything to start with and see what happens. * { margin: 0; }

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question (without your back story).

Answer (score 0):

The white border is caused by the margin on `<body>`, so remove it with:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

You can horizontally center an absolute positioned element with the [`translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/translate) property.

```
.navbar {
  left: 50%;
  translate: -50%;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu');
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}


/*navbar*/

.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  translate: -50%;
  right: 70;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar * {
  display: inline;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-nav {
  justify-content: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 0 #fff, -2px 0 #fff, 0 2px #fff, 0 -2px #fff, 1px 1px #fff, -1px -1px #fff, 1px -1px #fff, -1px 1px #fff;
}


/*main display text*/

#coverPage {
  background: url(https://wallpapers.com/images/hd/dark-shades-of-purple-j1bf61qb3t5kkk6h.webp)fixed right top;
  min-height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.main-display {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 20px black, -2px 1px 30px black;
}

#title {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.SE {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.bball {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 5000;
}

.gym {
  font-size: 17px;
}

#about-me {
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-me-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup" div>
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">about</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">projects</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<section id="coverPage">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="main-display">
          <h1 class="display-1" id="title" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic" data-aos-duration="2000">NADIR ESMAIL</h1>
          <h2 class="SE" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic" data-aos-duration="2000">software developer</h2>
          <h1 class="bball" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic" data-aos-duration="2000">Basketball fanatic</h1>
          <h1 class="gym" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic" data-aos-duration="2000">Gym enthusiast</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!--About me page-->
<section id="about-me">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="about-title">
        <h1 id="about-me-h1" class="display-5">About</h1>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</section>

















<!--  bootstrap and aos js  -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="nadir.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8c2adfc9c1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It worked, however now I have a white part in between my two backgrounds.

Comment: @NadirEsmail What two backgrounds? There is only one background image in the code you provided.